# How do I push the updated Gridview to Database?

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to make a windows form application in C#. I was trying to delete a particular row in Gridview and push the changes into the database. This delete does remove the row. All I want to do is push this updated gridview into the database.

```
         private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string ind = e.RowIndex.ToString();
            int myint = int.Parse(ind);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[myint]);

         }
```

This is the code I use for displaying the Database.

```
   using (SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LENOVO\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=SampleData"))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * from dbo. userpass";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, MyConn);
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
                bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
                sda.Update(dbdataset);
            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the the code you are using to fill datagrid in a function and call that function and refresh the grid before calling the function.

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this commercially I would suggest you fork out for an actual WinForms framework like SyncFusion/Telerik/DevExpress etc. Most of them should have a set of tools to directly bind one of their WinForm grids to a database table, and have all of the CRUD operations directly interact with the underlying table.

The other option is to use Entity Framework, with an Entity Framework DataSource control, that then binds to the grid, once again CRUD operations should just flow to the database, (however I would suggest you use the WPF controls with this approach).

At the end of the day, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a BindingSource so its simply a case of:

```
bSource.RemoveCurrent();
```

And at the same time delete it from the database using the [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method:

```
.CommandText = "DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE Identifier =" & PrimaryKey
```

Answer (score 0):

use DELETE SQL query to remove the row's data  and refresh the grid by calling the database connection method again and you will get the updated code